# How to set SoapUI test step's request value via Groovy

Tags: soapui

When using Groovy for SoapUI test suites, I'm able to read the response from a specific test step, e.g.:

```
responseString = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetUserService"].testRequest.response.responseContent;
log.info "responseString -" + responseString;
```

Now how can use Groovy programmatically send a request body to the test step, e.g. this GetUserService?

I could imagine it is something like this:

```
JSON_PayloadString="A JSON Payload String";
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetUserService"].testRequest.request.setValue(JSON_PayloadString);
testRunner.runTestStepByName("GetUserService")
```

But I always getting syntax errors.

Can anyone help on my question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set JSON element in SoapUI TestCase request using Groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748424/set-json-element-in-soapui-testcase-request-using-groovy-script)

Comment: Thanks @ophychius, your answer does help me resolve the issue. 
Another way to do it is:

testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Service1"].getTestRequest().setRequestContent(payload);
testRunner.runTestStepByName("Service1");